# string manipulation col_schema="col1 string,col2 int". I need to retrieve => "col1,col2"

Tags: python, string

I have a string `col_schema="col1 string,col2 int"`
Now I have to retrieve column names alone . something like this => `output="col1,col2"`
Tried doing below,

```
    name, value = col_list.split(' ')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       ValueError: too many values to unpack

```
     col_list_split    = col_list.split(',')
    >>> print col_list_split
    ['col1 string', 'col2 string']
    >>> name, value = col_list_split.split(' ')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each element on a space after splitting on a comma

```
col_list_split    = (x.split() for x in col_schema.split(','))
```

Then you have a list of lists, where the first element is the column name, which you can join on a comma

```
result = ','.join(x[0] for x in col_list_split)
```